# Calculate only working hours between dates in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Hello everyone I have written an oracle query which is calculating working according to 8 hours, but I want according to 8.5 hours result, there is a minor change but I am not getting it please help. Now according to the start and end date, it should return 8.5 working house, but it is returning 8 working hours please assist.

**Query**

```
with dates as (
              select  to_date('20-oct-2022 09:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_dt,
                     to_date('20-oct-2022 17:30:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_dt
             from  dual
              ),
        -- get  work hours for each date
        t as (
              select  case level
                        when 1 then greatest(start_dt,trunc(start_dt) + 8 / 24)
                        else trunc(start_dt) + level - 16 / 24
                      end start_dt,
                      case connect_by_isleaf
                        when 1 then least(end_dt,trunc(end_dt) + 17 / 24)
                        else trunc(start_dt) + level - 7 / 24
                      end end_dt
                from  dates
                connect by level <= trunc(end_dt) - trunc(start_dt) + 1
             )
select  sum(greatest(end_dt - start_dt,0)) * 24 work_hours
  from  t
  where trunc(start_dt) - trunc(start_dt,'iw') < 5
```

Comment: Including sample data and your current and expected results for that data (as formatted text, and optionally a fiddle) would help. But you might just need to change `+ 17 / 24` to `+ 17.5 / 24` to make that refer to 17:30 like your CTE? And maybe `- 7 / 24` to `- 6.5 / 24`?

Comment: after this when i input   (select to_date('29-Nov-2022 9:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_dt,
                       to_date('30-Nov-2022 17:30:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_dt
                 from  dual) it giving me 18, should it not give 17 hours?

Comment: Well... what do you consider working hours? Your code seems to imply 08:00 to 17:00, which is 9 hours, not 8? So should it be 08:00 to 16:30, or 09:00 to 17:30, or something else?

Comment: yes i want  09:00 to 17:30 scenario kindly help

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to generate all the days; you can directly calculate the number of hours:

```sql
SELECT start_dt,
       end_dt,
       ROUND(
         (
           -- Calculate the full weeks difference from the start of ISO weeks.
           ( TRUNC( end_dt, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_dt, 'IW' ) ) * 8.5 * (5/7)
           -- Add the full days for the final week.
           + LEAST( TRUNC( end_dt ) - TRUNC( end_dt, 'IW' ), 5 ) * 8.5
           -- Subtract the full days from the days of the week before the start date.
           - LEAST( TRUNC( start_dt ) - TRUNC( start_dt, 'IW' ), 5 ) * 8.5
           -- Add the hours of the final day
           + CASE 
             WHEN end_dt - TRUNC( end_dt, 'IW' ) < 5 -- Weekday
             THEN LEAST(
                    GREATEST(
                      end_dt  - (TRUNC( end_dt ) + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE),
                      0
                    ) * 24,
                    8.5
                  )
             ELSE 0
             END
           -- Subtract the hours of the day before the range starts.
           - CASE 
             WHEN start_dt - TRUNC( start_dt, 'IW' ) < 5 -- Weekday
             THEN LEAST(
                    GREATEST(
                      start_dt - (TRUNC( start_dt ) + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE),
                      0
                    ) * 24,
                    8.5
                  )
             ELSE 0
             END
         ),
         15 -- Number of decimal places
       ) AS work_hours_diff
FROM   dates;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dates (start_dt, end_dt) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-10-20' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-10-20' + INTERVAL '17:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-20' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-10-21' + INTERVAL '17:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-19' + INTERVAL '23:46:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-11-21' + INTERVAL '12:06:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-18' + INTERVAL '17:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-11-21' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-19' + INTERVAL '12:26:45' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-11-21' + INTERVAL '11:02:15' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-21' + INTERVAL '11:02:15' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2022-11-19' + INTERVAL '12:26:45' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| START_DT | END_DT | WORK_HOURS_DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-20 09:00:00 (THU) | 2022-10-20 17:30:00 (THU) | 8.5 |
| 2022-10-20 10:00:00 (THU) | 2022-10-21 17:30:00 (FRI) | 16 |
| 2022-11-19 23:46:00 (SAT) | 2022-11-21 12:06:00 (MON) | 3.1 |
| 2022-11-18 17:30:00 (FRI) | 2022-11-21 09:00:00 (MON) | 0 |
| 2022-11-19 12:26:45 (SAT) | 2022-11-21 11:02:15 (MON) | 2.0375 |
| 2022-11-21 11:02:15 (MON) | 2022-11-19 12:26:45 (SAT) | -2.0375 |

*Note: the negative value is valid as the start date is after the end date for that row.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hU5z5Gnm)

Comment: whenever it gives value with minus sign there is  something wrong

Comment: @Iqrakhan Added a check for weekend start/end dates.

Comment: @Iqrakhan A negative value should be given when the start date is after the end date; however, when the start date is before or equal to the end date then the output should be positive (and I've fixed the bug for weekend start dates that was erroneously producing negatives).